# Angular Accordion Panel Color Change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an accordion that dynamically has html controls added to it. I am trying to figure out how to change the color of the accordion's panel to yellow when any of the child controls become dirty; has been touched.
Here is the plnkr code that I have so far.  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/MdMWysRUEtGOyEJUfheh?p=preview

Layout below.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.cs" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="bookcontroller">
    <accordion id="accordion_{{$index+((currentPage-1)*20)+1}}" close-others="true">
  <accordion-group is-open="isopen" >
       <accordion-heading class="container-fluid grey">
        Book Hearder
       </accordion-heading>
    <form name="form">
      <div class="form-row" ng-repeat="record in records">
       <table>
          <tr ng-formfield></tr>
       </table>
     </div>
    </form>
  </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
  </body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT.JS code

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);


    app.controller('bookcontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.records=[
          {
           RecordId: 91,
           Type:'Label',
           Label: 'Favoritebook'
         },
          {
           RecordId: 92,
           Type:    'Dropdown',
            Label:  'Favoritebook',
            DDLValue: [{ 'value': '1', 'text': 'HarryPotter' }, 
                       { 'value': '2', 'text': 'StarGate' }]

          },
          {
           RecordId: 93,
           Type:'Text',
           Label: 'The TextBox'
         }]

    }
]);




app.directive('ngFormfield', function ($compile) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                if (scope.record.Type == 'Label') {

                    element.html('<label togglecolor type="label" ng-model="record.DDLValue.value"/>' + scope.record.Label + '</label>');

                }
                else if (scope.record.Type == 'Text') {
                    element.html('<td colspan="8">'+scope.record.Label + ': <input togglecolor type="text" name="fname"></td>');
                }
                else if (scope.record.Type == 'Dropdown') {
                    element.html('<td colspan="8"><select class="btn btn-default dropdown" togglecolor ng-model=record.DDLValue.value ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in record.DDLValue"></select></td>');
                }

              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        }
    });

 app.directive('togglecolor', [function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
            scope.$watch(function() {return element.attr('class'); }, function(newValue){
                debugger;
                if (element.hasClass('ng-dirty')) {
                  element.parent().addClass('toggle-yellow');
                } else {
                  element.parent().removeClass('toggle-yellow');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Any idea how to get this togglecolor directive working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the togglecolor directive. It appears that element.parent() is not the element whose color you want to change.

I would recommend selecting the element that you want to change explicitly.

In html, load jQuery and add an id to the element whose colour you want to change:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    ...

    <accordion-group id="bookHeader" is-open="isopen" >
```

In js, use jQuery to select the element by id and change the colour if it is dirty:

```
    if (element.hasClass('ng-dirty')) {
      $('#bookHeader').addClass('toggle-yellow');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass to accomplish this. Either by attaching an ngChange directive on your forms that affects a variable in the controller.

Attaching an additional watcher adds performance overhead, so you want to avoid that when possible.

Further, it might not make sense to use a table for this form. It looks like you're using it for formatting?